# Minipage with vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: minipage

I want to create a minipage like the one shown in the picture. Any ideas how to do it? Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: You might want to look at `mdframed` or the newer (and possibly better) `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Manuel: I'm using \documentclass{book}, can I use them? Could you give me a simple example?

Comment: Yes, they are packages. Look for the documentation (texdoc, or may be google) or even in this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility admitting page breaks using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
   freelance,
   breakable,
   title=#1,
   left=0pt,
   right=0pt,
   width=.9\textwidth,
   enlarge left by=.1\textwidth,
   coltitle=black,
   frame code={},
   interior titled code={
     \draw[myblue,ultra thick] 
       ([yshift=5pt]frame.south west) |- ([xshift=60pt,yshift=-4pt]title.south west);
   }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{mybox}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

Comment: Very nice, I like it! But, I would like to push the box a bit to the right, similar to a minipage that extends for instance 0.9\text width. Besides, I also like to modify the distance between where the text starts and the vertical line. Is that using "[xshift=60pt,yshift=-4pt]"?

Comment: @LatexQuest Please see my updated answer. The relevant keys are `left`, `right`, `width` and `enlarge left by`.

Comment: @LatexQuest do you want the length of the horizontal line to automatically adapt to the length of the title?

Comment: thanks a lot. The one Herbert suggested is working that way.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a tabular:

```
%\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}%% maybe needed if you have a special class
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%%% Delete it if your special class alread loads it
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}%
   \hfill\tabularx{0.8\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\vrule width 2pt} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l}\kern\tabcolsep\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
  {\endtabularx\par\medskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{The title with some more text in the title}
Onyl some text here
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{The title}
\blindtext
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want. It works perfectly when I run it separately but when I add it to my document, it returns this error => Option clash for package xcolor. Next line complains about => \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}.

Comment: The package `xcolor` is already loaded by you. Write just before the documentclass `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` and then delete the line `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. See my edited answer

Comment: I did it, but I get some other weird problem. It says no room for a new dim check .... looks like the problem returns to many packages I have ... or a conflict :(

Comment: `\usepackage{etex}` will help

Comment: could you please check my related question here=> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194118/minipage-style-with-lines